# AKS - Kube State metrics Supported versions

Tags: azure-aks

I am using AKS and recently upgraded to AKS 1.24.6.
How to determine what version of kube state metrics supports what AKS version?

I am looking at this https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics

I am unable to understand the matrix given between Kube state metrics and Client-Go version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the matrix, you can either use v2.5.0 or v2.6.0.